# Saving a model form instance in django

Tags: django, models

I'm trying to create a site where users can submit blog posts (which uses a model form).  I then also have a view to search for a post based on it's article number which brings up the model form for editing, and then you can submit updates.  What i have works, i just feel like there's probably a better way to do this.

It feels like i don't need the "update_results" view and can just combine it with the "submit_post" view.

Here is what i have:

views.py

```
def submit_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = Information_Form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/submit')

    else:
        form = Information_Form

    return render_to_response('submit_post.html', {'form': form},  context_instance=RequestContext(request))



def search_results(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':

        query = request.GET['q']
        results = Information.objects.get(article_number=query)

        form = Information_Form(instance=results)


        return render_to_response('search_results.html', {'results': results, 'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))


def update_results(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        article = request.POST['article_number']
        x = Information.objects.get(article_number=article)

        form = Information_Form(request.POST, instance=x)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/update_results')
    else:
        form = Information_Form()
    return render_to_response('submit_post.html', {'form': form},  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it's okay to have two different views for each action : create, and update.

However, if you want more concise code, you can maybe use [Class Based Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/), like this :

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView
from myapp.models import BlogPost # replace with your own model
from myapp.forms import BlogPost_Form # Replace with your own form

class BlogPostCreate(CreateView):
    model = BlogPost
    fields = ['title', 'content']   # define fields you want for the form
                                    # or uncomment the line bellow to use your own form class
    # form_class = BlogPost_Form


class BlogPostUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = BlogPost
    fields = ['name', 'content']
```

This way, you don't have to reproduce the form handling logic for each view.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can combine create and update with relative ease by checking for the presence of article_number.  If one is supplied, then upon POST, update the existing article, and upon GET, display the existing article.  If no article_number is present, display a blank form upon GET and save a new article upon POST.

```
def create_or_edit_article(request):

    article_number = request.GET.get('article_number' None)
    if article_number:
        instance = Information.objects.get(article_number=article_number)
    else:
        instance = None

    # by using 'or None', this will work as if request.POST was not
    # passed when it is a GET.
    form = Information_Form(request.POST or None, instance=instance)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            # you do not have to use `commit=True` here because that is the default
            # behavior. Use `commit=` when False is a possibility.
            form.save()
            # here you can decide where to redirect on success.  eg:
            if instance:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/after_edit_url')
             return HttpResponseRedirect('/after_insert_url')
            # BTW you should really use reverse() to get these urls. 

    return render_to_response('article_form.html', {'form': form}, 
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

So, with the code above, if you GET `/the_url/?article_id=12345`, it will display that article.  If you submit that form back to the same url, it will save the changes.  Don't use any `action=` in your `<form>` tag and it will submit where it should.

In your search results template, generate links which contain the article_id as shown and you can then edit any article with just one view.

One additional thing I will add is that the 'Django style' for URLs would be more like

`/myapp/article/` <- view (GET) list of articles.

`/myapp/article/12345/` <- view (GET)/save (POST) article #12345

`/myapp/article/add/` <- display blank article (GET)/save new article (POST)

To do this, you would set up regex's in your urls.conf to match each of these and dispatch the correct view function.  If you use a 'named group' named article_number in your url regex, it will be passed as a kwarg to your view.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#named-groups